# JDBC Connection error when inserting data

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsp, jdbc

I'am fairly new to java programming and I'm trying all morning to connect a project I've made in eclipse with a database in Mysql.
When I run the code I don't receive any errors. But when I want to store everything into the database I get the following error message :

```
 org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page 
 /DBList_version1.jsp at line 27

 24:            String name = request.getParameter("name");
 25:            String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
 26:            int points = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("points"));
 27:            stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO STUDENT(name, firstName, points) VALUES('" > + name + "','" + firstName + "'," + points + ")");
 28:        }
 29:        rst = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM STUDENT");
 30: %>
```

So if I'm correct the error says there's something wrong when inserting the data into the database.

I triple checked everything and I can't seem to find out what the problem is.

If I can manage to find out how to store everything into my database my problem would be solved and 90% of my project!

Thanks in advance

UPDATE :

```
public void executeInsert(String table, String name, String firstName, int points) {

        try {
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO " + table + " VALUES('" + name + "','" + firstName + "'," + points + ")");
            stmt.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex);
        }
    }`
```

`

Comment: Where exactly do you get the jdbc error? All you provide here is the JasperException.

Comment: Where comes the `>` in `VALUES('" >` from? Is it part of your statement?

Comment: I think the Java code in your JSP does not compile and as Jens indicated, it is most likely due to a syntax error. Remove the '>' at the start of your VALUES part of the query.

Comment: @Jens That was a typo on my behalve, sorry!

Comment: @f1sh Yeah sure sorry :

java.lang.NullPointerException
 org.apache.jsp.DBList_005fversion1_jsp._jspService(DBList_005fversion1_jsp.java:80)
 org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

Comment: @Florian No it wasn't due to a syntax error. :/

Comment: why don't you try with `PreparedStatement` to avoid such errors?

Comment: I've added the insert method

Comment: @Richaar do you see any exeprions in your server logfile?

Comment: From what you can see from the stacktrace and the method given by you, it may be a missing connection, i.e. the conn reference pointing to null. All SQL / database related errors are caught with the try-catch-block. What else can be null? It could be the statement but I can't remeber that I ever got a null reference from conn.createStatement(). But it's wild guessing as the stacktrace is not very helpful. But in the end there is not much accessing of references that may be null.

Comment: I fixed it!
It was an Eclipse error ...

Answer (score 1):

when i was new to JDBC,i always try to run query MYSQL and if it works correctly i would add it to java insert statement and format it accordingly. This will make less syntax errors. Try it. By the way I am still new.